# The Same Action Called Unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The layout of this ASP.NET MVC application looks like the following (this is a mobile web app):

1. **Page 1** is question 1 -> Submit the form and return **Page 2's View**
2. **Page 2** is question 2 -> Submit the form and return **Page 3's View**
3. **Page 3** is the final question -> Submit to complete processing

After each of the form submits, I'd expect the next page's view to appear and submit accordingly.  But, what's really happening is on **Page 1** when I hit the submit button, it *shows* **Page 2's** view, but now that I'm on **Page 2** and I hit submit on that page, it calls the Action of **Page 1's** `HttpPost`.

What would cause **Page 2's** submit to call **Page 1's** `HttpPost` Action?

Here is the basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel myModel)
{
    return View("Page2", myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page2(MyModel myModel)
{
    return View("Page3", myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page3(MyModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something and complete
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is obviously oversimplified, but you should get the idea.  The `Page2`'s View gets rendered no problem.  But on that page when the submit button is hit, it goes right back to the `HttpPost` of `Index()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: what form action url gets generated on page2?

Comment: The controllers probably have less to do with what you are describing than how you are calling them. Perhaps you can describe how you are calling your methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happens is because when you use mvc's `BeginForm` HTML helper it submits to 
the rendering action, not to the action that equals to the view name, but you can fix it!

Two options:

**First**: Set the values for the controller and action in the HTML helper:

```
@BeginForm("Page3", "controllerName")
```

**Second**: redirect to the action instead of returning the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel myModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Page2", myModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page2(MyModel myModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Page3", myModel);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  The first option is exactly what I was looking for.  Complete oversight on my part.  Thanks!!!!